# Convert Salesforce query SOAP response into CSV using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, salesforce, wso2-esb

I am getting below SOAP response as salesforce query result.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
  <LimitInfoHeader>
     <limitInfo>
        <current>31363</current>
        <limit>92000</limit>
        <type>API REQUESTS</type>
     </limitInfo>
  </LimitInfoHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
   <queryResponse>
     <result xsi:type="QueryResult">
        <done>true</done>
        <queryLocator xsi:nil="true" />
        <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
           <sf:type>Item__c</sf:type>
           <sf:Id xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:Name>100000031</sf:Name>
           <sf:Active__c>false</sf:Active__c>
           <sf:Active_for_B2B__c>true</sf:Active_for_B2B__c>
           <sf:Active_for_B2C__c>true</sf:Active_for_B2C__c>
           <sf:Active_for_Marketplace__c>true</sf:Active_for_Marketplace__c>
           <sf:Average_Cost__c xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:B2B_Selling_Price__c>100</sf:B2B_Selling_Price__c>
           <sf:B2C_Selling_Price__c>100</sf:B2C_Selling_Price__c>
           <sf:Brand__c>a0h9000000BAHOkAAP</sf:Brand__c>
           <sf:Breadth__c xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:Category__c>a0j9000000LnHliAAF</sf:Category__c>
           <sf:CategoryLink1__c>scat066</sf:CategoryLink1__c>
           <sf:CategoryLink1Domain__c>scat004</sf:CategoryLink1Domain__c>
           <sf:Task_Owner__c xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:Category_Owner__c>abc@test.test</sf:Category_Owner__c>
           <sf:Category_Segment__c>Office Supplies</sf:Category_Segment__c>
           <sf:Class__c>a0j9000000LnKdwAAF</sf:Class__c>
           <sf:EAN_Code__c>10000000001</sf:EAN_Code__c>
           <sf:EDD__c>5.0</sf:EDD__c>
           <sf:Gen_Prod_Posting_Group__c>a0Y9000000C3zGSEAZ</sf:Gen_Prod_Posting_Group__c>
           <sf:Height__c xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:Inventory_Posting_Group__c>a0d9000000ADKw3AAH</sf:Inventory_Posting_Group__c>
           <sf:Inventory_Type__c xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:Item_Tracking_Code__c xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:Last_Direct_Cost__c xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:Length__c xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:Long_Description__c>Parker Ball Pen</sf:Long_Description__c>
           <sf:MRP__c>200.0</sf:MRP__c>
           <sf:Requested_By1__c xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:Sales_Type__c>Catalogue</sf:Sales_Type__c>
           <sf:Service_Item_Group__c xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:Short_Description__c>Parker Ball Pen</sf:Short_Description__c>
           <sf:Sub_Category__c xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:Tax_Group__c>a0e9000000K7gdsAAB</sf:Tax_Group__c>
           <sf:Title__c>Parker Ball Pen</sf:Title__c>
           <sf:Type__c>a0k9000000VRpwCAAT</sf:Type__c>
           <sf:Unit_of_Measure__c>a0i90000009jt3fAAA</sf:Unit_of_Measure__c>
           <sf:Unit_Price__c>100.0</sf:Unit_Price__c>
           <sf:Weight__c xsi:nil="true" />
        </records>
        <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
           <sf:type>Item__c</sf:type>
           <sf:Id xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:Name>100000032</sf:Name>
           <sf:Active__c>true</sf:Active__c>
           <sf:Active_for_B2B__c>true</sf:Active_for_B2B__c>
           <sf:Active_for_B2C__c>true</sf:Active_for_B2C__c>
           <sf:Active_for_Marketplace__c>true</sf:Active_for_Marketplace__c>
           <sf:Average_Cost__c>200.0</sf:Average_Cost__c>
           <sf:B2B_Selling_Price__c>90</sf:B2B_Selling_Price__c>
           <sf:B2C_Selling_Price__c>100</sf:B2C_Selling_Price__c>
           <sf:Brand__c>a0h9000000BAHLFAA5</sf:Brand__c>
           <sf:Breadth__c>2.0</sf:Breadth__c>
           <sf:Category__c>a0j9000000LnHliAAF</sf:Category__c>
           <sf:CategoryLink1__c>CategoryLink1</sf:CategoryLink1__c>
           <sf:CategoryLink1Domain__c>CategoryLink1Domain</sf:CategoryLink1Domain__c>
           <sf:Task_Owner__c xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:Category_Owner__c>test@test.test</sf:Category_Owner__c>
           <sf:Category_Segment__c>Office Supplies</sf:Category_Segment__c>
           <sf:Class__c>a0j9000000LnKdwAAF</sf:Class__c>
           <sf:EAN_Code__c>EAN Code</sf:EAN_Code__c>
           <sf:EDD__c>5.0</sf:EDD__c>
           <sf:Gen_Prod_Posting_Group__c>a0Y9000000C3zGSEAZ</sf:Gen_Prod_Posting_Group__c>
           <sf:Height__c>3.0</sf:Height__c>
           <sf:Inventory_Posting_Group__c>a0d9000000ADKw3AAH</sf:Inventory_Posting_Group__c>
           <sf:Inventory_Type__c>Inventoried</sf:Inventory_Type__c>
           <sf:Item_Tracking_Code__c>a0g9000000MdvlwAAB</sf:Item_Tracking_Code__c>
           <sf:Last_Direct_Cost__c>400.0</sf:Last_Direct_Cost__c>
           <sf:Length__c>1.0</sf:Length__c>
           <sf:Long_Description__c>Long Description Long Description Long Description</sf:Long_Description__c>
           <sf:MRP__c>100.0</sf:MRP__c>
           <sf:Requested_By1__c>test@test</sf:Requested_By1__c>
           <sf:Sales_Type__c>Catalogue</sf:Sales_Type__c>
           <sf:Service_Item_Group__c>a0f9000000HajP5AAJ</sf:Service_Item_Group__c>
           <sf:Short_Description__c>Long Description</sf:Short_Description__c>
           <sf:Sub_Category__c xsi:nil="true" />
           <sf:Tax_Group__c>a0e9000000K7gddAAB</sf:Tax_Group__c>
           <sf:Title__c>PEN-bello</sf:Title__c>
           <sf:Type__c>a0k9000000VRpwCAAT</sf:Type__c>
           <sf:Unit_of_Measure__c>a0i90000009jt3fAAA</sf:Unit_of_Measure__c>
           <sf:Unit_Price__c>300.0</sf:Unit_Price__c>
           <sf:Weight__c>4.0</sf:Weight__c>
        </records>
        <size>2</size>
     </result>
   </queryResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

And I am using below CSV to convert it into CSV.

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/child::*">
    <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>,</xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="position()  = last()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/><xsl:text> 
</xsl:text></xsl:if>
```

The result after transformation is blank but the expected result is below .

The present outcome of execution is blank.
And the expected result is below

Item__c,,100000031,false,true,true,true,,100,100,a0h9000000BAHOkAAP,,a0j9000000LnHliAAF,scat066,scat004,,sandeep.gala@staples.in,Office Supplies,a0j9000000LnKdwAAF,10000000001,5.0,a0Y9000000C3zGSEAZ,,a0d9000000ADKw3AAH,,,,,Parker Ball Pen,200.0,,Catalogue,,Parker Ball Pen,,a0e9000000K7gdsAAB,Parker Ball Pen,a0k9000000VRpwCAAT,a0i90000009jt3fAAA,100.0,,Item__c,,100000032,true,true,true,true,200.0,90,100,a0h9000000BAHLFAA5,2.0,a0j9000000LnHliAAF,CategoryLink1,CategoryLink1Domain,,sandeep.gala@staples.in,Office Supplies,a0j9000000LnKdwAAF,EAN Code,5.0,a0Y9000000C3zGSEAZ,3.0,a0d9000000ADKw3AAH,Inventoried,a0g9000000MdvlwAAB,400.0,1.0,Long Description Long Description Long Description,100.0,requested.by@staples.in,Catalogue,a0f9000000HajP5AAJ,Long Description,,a0e9000000K7gddAAB,PEN-bello,a0k9000000VRpwCAAT,a0i90000009jt3fAAA,300.0,4.0

Please help me to get only records in csv format.

Comment: your input XML contains a default namespace `xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"`. Search this site for examples.

Comment: "*this is not returning the proper result.*" And what *is* "the proper result"?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you only want to have "records", I guess you want something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:soap="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//soap:records[1]/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::soap:records"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="soap:records">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/><xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It uses the names of the childs of the first `records` element as headline for the CSV output, then applies the template for `records`, which puts out the text content of each child, separating them by comma, of course.

Comment: Thaks cis, The xslt is transforming properly in xslt tester tools but not working in wso2.

Comment: Then I cannot help you, sorry, as I'm not familiar with wso2. If possible, change your XSTL processor.